# Xamarin Forms Cross Platform App Resource File with StringFormat

Tags: xamarin.forms, string-formatting, globalization, resource-files

Is there a way to apply a StringFormat to a value from a Resource file.  I basically want something like this:

Text="{localapp:Translate Port, StringFormat='{0}:'}"

Basically I don't want to put punctuation in the Resource file so I can reuse the value in more places in my app.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to add a further property in our translate MarkupExtension to support StringFormat:

```
[ContentProperty("Text")]
public class TranslateExtension : IMarkupExtension
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    public string StringFormat { get; set; }

    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Text))
            return null;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringFormat))
            return string.Format(StringFormat, Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(Text));

        return Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(Text);
    }
}
```

Now we can use StringFormat in XAML like this:

```
<Label Text="{utilities:Translate Port, StringFormat='{0}:'}"/>
```

Now assuming we already defined a resourse such as *Port="MyPort"* , the output of the label would be:

```
MyPort:
```

Comment: So my TranslateExtension class already had a ProvideValue function in it.  I had to merge / move things around and I got it to work.  I up-voted this answer but I am going to provide the complete ProvideValue function code I used in another answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you VahidShir for the jump start and basic core of the solution.  Here is the actual code for my ProvideValue function in my TranslateExtension class that appears to be working.

```
    public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        if (Text == null)
            return string.Empty;

        var translation = ResMgr.Value.GetString(Text, ci);
        if (translation == null)
        {
#if DEBUG
            throw new ArgumentException(
                string.Format("Key '{0}' was not found in resources '{1}' for culture '{2}'.", Text, ResourceId, ci.Name),
                "Text");
#else
            translation = Text; // HACK: returns the key, which GETS DISPLAYED TO THE USER
#endif
        }

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(StringFormat))
            translation =  string.Format(StringFormat, translation);

        return translation;
    }
```

I hope this helps out other people.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to use a value from a Resource file.

Creating a Resource file **ConstValue.cs**:

```
public static class ConstValue
{
   public static string ValueOne { get; set; } = "abc";
}
```

And also need a value model **ValueModel.cs**:

```
public class ValueModel()
{

    public string  Value { get; set;}

    public ValueModel()
    {
        Value = ConstValue.ValueOne;
    }
}
```

Then in **ContentPage.cs** , using this model

```
BindingContext = new ValueModel();
```

Last in **Xaml** can be used as follow:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Value,StringFormat='This is {0}'}" />
```

**Note**:

If directly using value from class ,it will not work . Such as:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Source={x:Static localapp:ConstValue.ValueOne},StringFormat='this is {0}'}"/>
```

The most important is it needs to bind model to use value from class.This is also match with MVVM Architecture.

**Alternatively**:

Using Xaml Resources can do that:

```
<StackLayout.Resources>
    <x:String x:Key="stringkey">123</x:String>
</StackLayout.Resources>

<Label Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource Key=stringkey},StringFormat='the value is {0}'}" />
```

Comment: While I have not tried this - I believe it would work.  However it seems more involved that the previous solution provided.

Comment: @GeorgeMCeaserJr Thanks for replying , glad you solved it !